# c library function for tcp checksum

Tags: c, tcp, checksum

Is there a C library function for calculating or validating a TCP checksum? I saw a few handcoded functions, but thought there must be a lib function somewhere.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803201/is-there-a-pre-existing-function-or-code-i-can-use-to-compute-a-tcp-segment-chec?lq=1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845178/c-programming-tcp-checksum  it might be worth specifying your environment.

Comment: If you're on Linux, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497941/tcp-checksum-and-tcp-offloading?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no standard library function. Everyone just sort of copy&pastes the same [`in_cksum`](http://code.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=in_cksum&type=cs) function whenever they need it. Silly, eh?

Comment: This link is broken because Google Code Search was discontinued in 2013.